# Adjust prices on stock portfolio based on quantity and price

Tags: python, pandas, stock, weighted-average

I am trying to adjust my portfolio of stocks and trying to calculate the adjusted mean price (which is a form of weighted-average).

Here is sample data:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

sample_dict = {'ticker': {1: 'ABCD',
  2: 'ABCD', 3: 'ABCD', 4: 'ABCD', 5: 'ABCD', 6: 'ABCD', 8: 'EFGH',
  9: 'EFGH', 10: 'EFGH', 11: 'EFGH', 12: 'EFGH', 13: 'EFGH'},
 'Date': {1: "2018, 1, 10",   2: "2018, 1, 20",
  3: "2018, 2, 7", 4: "2018, 4, 14",
  5: "2018, 5, 25", 6: "2018, 7, 4",
  8: "2018, 1, 10", 9: "2018, 1, 20",
  10: "2018, 2, 7", 11: "2018, 4, 14",
  12: "2018, 5, 25", 13: "2018, 7, 4"},
 'Sell_buy': {1: 'buy', 2: 'buy',  3: 'sell', 4: 'buy', 5: 'sell', 6: 'buy',
  8: 'buy', 9: 'buy', 10: 'buy', 11: 'buy', 12: 'sell', 13: 'sell'},
 'Qtd': {1: 100.0, 2: 300.0, 3: 200.0, 4: 500.0, 5: 600.0, 6: 500.0,
  8: 300.0, 9: 300.0, 10: 200.0, 11: 200.0, 12: 700.0, 13: 100.0},
 'Price': {1: 8.0, 2: 10.0, 3: 12.0, 4: 9.0, 5: 13.0, 6: 14.0,
  8: 8.0, 9: 10.0, 10: 12.0, 11: 9.0, 12: 13.0, 13: 14.0},
 'Costs': {1: 10.93, 2: 12.52, 3: 11.39, 4: 14.5, 5: 14.68, 6: 14.96,
  8: 10.93, 9: 12.52, 10: 11.39, 11: 14.5, 12: 14.68, 13: 14.96}}

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
sample_df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(sample_df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.date
```

I was able to get the get an updated Adjusted quantity (based on buys and sells) without any issues:

```
#to calculate adjusted quantity. this works as expected
sample_df['Adj Qtd'] = sample_df.apply(lambda x: ((x.Sell_buy == "buy") - (x.Sell_buy == "sell")) * x['Qtd'], axis = 1)
sample_df['Adj Qtd'] = sample_df.groupby('ticker')['Adj Qtd'].cumsum()
```

However, I am not able to get the correct Adjusted Price.
The condition here is if I sell a stock, my Adjusted Price should not change and remain the same as the last adjusted price when the buy was made for that stock.

I've tried the following to achieve this goal:

```
#Adjust Price. Works good until I reach the row where a sell was made
sample_df['Adjusted Price'] = sample_df.apply(lambda x: ((x.Sell_buy == "buy") - (x.Sell_buy == "sell")) * (x["Price"] * x["Qtd"] + x["Costs"]), axis = 1)
sample_df['Adjusted Price'] = sample_df.groupby('ticker')['Adjusted Price'].cumsum().div(sample_df['Adj Qtd'])
```

I could partially correct the adjusted prices on sell rows with the following:

```
# When it's a "sell", adjusted price is the same from above
sample_df.loc[sample_df['Sell_buy'] == 'sell',['Adjusted Price']] = np.NaN
sample_df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

    ticker  Date    Sell_buy        Qtd Price   Costs   Adj Qtd Adjusted Price
1   ABCD    2018-10-01  buy       100.0 8.0     10.93   100.0   8.109300
2   ABCD    2018-01-20  buy       300.0 10.0    12.52   400.0   9.558625
3   ABCD    2018-07-02  sell      200.0 12.0    11.39   200.0   9.558625
4   ABCD    2018-04-14  buy       500.0 9.0     14.50   700.0   8.466514
5   ABCD    2018-05-25  sell      600.0 13.0    14.68   100.0   8.466514
6   ABCD    2018-04-07  buy       500.0 14.0    14.96   600.0   8.544733
8   EFGH    2018-10-01  buy       300.0 8.0     10.93   300.0   8.036433
9   EFGH    2018-01-20  buy       300.0 10.0    12.52   600.0   9.039083
10  EFGH    2018-07-02  buy       200.0 12.0    11.39   800.0   9.793550
11  EFGH    2018-04-14  buy       200.0 9.0     14.50   1000.0  9.649340
12  EFGH    2018-05-25  sell      700.0 13.0    14.68   300.0   9.649340
13  EFGH    2018-04-07  sell      100.0 14.0    14.96   200.0   9.649340
```

This would work perfectly if there is no "sell" between "buy"s (as it did for the stock EFGH in this example).
To be clear, when the transaction is a "sell", we must ignore adjusting the price and use the last adjusted price in the last buy type transaction for that particular stock.

I did all these calculus in excel and the output should be the following:
For further clarification, the excel formula for that selected cell was:
`=IF(C3="buy";(I2*G2+D3*E3+F3)/G3;IF(G3<>0;I2;0))`

[image: Expected output base on excel sheet]

I've also tried .groupby("ticker").apply() a function using shift() in order to use prior values from rows above, but I've failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a nice, simple solution to this. The problem is that calculating adjusted price depends on the previous value of adjusted price, which prevents the use of vectorization or shift().

So, here's the ugly solution. :)

First step is to use a groupby, to separate it by ticker symbol. Then, it loops over all the rows in that group, and calculates a weighted average of the price to get the current shares, and the previous price. Then, it adds that list as a column in the dataframe.

```py
def weighted_average(a, b, a_weight):
    """Take an average of a and b, with a weighted by a_weight"""
    assert 0 <= a_weight <= 1
    return a * a_weight + b * (1 - a_weight)

def get_adjusted_price_for_ticker(single_ticker_df):
    adjusted_price = 0
    current_shares = 0
    prices = []
    for _, row in single_ticker_df.iterrows():
        is_buy = row["Sell_buy"] == "buy"
        qtd = row["Qtd"]
        if is_buy:
            current_shares += qtd
            cost_per_share = (qtd * row["Price"] + row["Costs"]) / qtd
            proportion_of_new_shares = qtd / current_shares
            adjusted_price = weighted_average(cost_per_share, adjusted_price, proportion_of_new_shares)
        else:
            current_shares -= qtd
        prices.append(adjusted_price)

    single_ticker_df["Adjusted Price"] = prices
    return single_ticker_df

def get_adjusted_price(df):
    return df.groupby("ticker").apply(get_adjusted_price_for_ticker)

get_adjusted_price(sample_df)
```

Output:

```
   ticker        Date Sell_buy    Qtd  Price  Costs  Adjusted Price
1    ABCD  2018-10-01      buy  100.0    8.0  10.93        8.109300
2    ABCD  2018-01-20      buy  300.0   10.0  12.52        9.558625
3    ABCD  2018-07-02     sell  200.0   12.0  11.39        9.558625
4    ABCD  2018-04-14      buy  500.0    9.0  14.50        9.180321
5    ABCD  2018-05-25     sell  600.0   13.0  14.68        9.180321
6    ABCD  2018-04-07      buy  500.0   14.0  14.96       13.221654
8    EFGH  2018-10-01      buy  300.0    8.0  10.93        8.036433
9    EFGH  2018-01-20      buy  300.0   10.0  12.52        9.039083
10   EFGH  2018-07-02      buy  200.0   12.0  11.39        9.793550
11   EFGH  2018-04-14      buy  200.0    9.0  14.50        9.649340
12   EFGH  2018-05-25     sell  700.0   13.0  14.68        9.649340
13   EFGH  2018-04-07     sell  100.0   14.0  14.96        9.649340
```

Comment: Thank you, @Nick. We also could remove all lines related to `current_shares` (including that else statement) using `proportion_of_new_shares = qtd / row["Adj Qtd"]` instead.

Comment: Since we will always start with a "buy", I thought a lot in a way where, if the row is a "sell", repeat the adjusted price above, if is not, then use my solution  `sample_df['Adjusted Price'] = sample_df.apply(lambda x: ((x.Sell_buy == "buy") - (x.Sell_buy == "sell")) * (x["Price"] * x["Qtd"] + x["Costs"]), axis = 1)`  followed by `sample_df['Adjusted Price'] = sample_df.groupby('ticker')['Adjusted Price'].cumsum().div(sample_df['Adj Qtd'])`.  But I couldn't  figure out a nice simple solution either.